# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface, but it is not an abstract class and it's not an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, mvvm-light, system.reactive

I've got two classes, neither of them are abstract, nor are either of them an interface.

IFileInfoClass:

```
 public class IFileInfo
 {
    #region Class Variables
    /// <summary>The file name.</summary>
    private string fileName = String.Empty;
    /// <summary>The file path.</summary>
    private string filePath = String.Empty;
    /// <summary>The date time stamp modified.</summary>
    private DateTime dateTimeStampModified = DateTime.Now;
    #endregion Class Variables

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IFileInfo"/> class.</summary>
    public IFileInfo() { }
 ...
 //Some Public Properties and another constructor...ect...
 ...
 }
```

Then in the calling class I've got like this:

```
 public IObservable<IFileInfo> GetFilesList()
    {
        IObservable<IFileInfo> files = new IObservable<IFileInfo>(); //ERROR HERE
    }
```

But when I go to compile I get en error:
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

```
 'System.IObservable<MyNameSpace.Models.IFileInfo>'
```

But it's not an abstract class nor is it an Interface...so what gives?
Does creating an IObservable collection of the class some how make it abstract?

FYI: IObservable is coming from MVVM-Light Galasoft.

I mean I know I cannot create an instance of an abstract class or interface, because abstract classes and interfaces don't do anything, nor are they supposed to, but that's not what I'm trying to do here! What am I missing?

A little history, I did try to create it as an implementation of the FileInfo class, thanks to some other suggestions from other sites, then I found out that of course Microsoft has made this into a sealed class, which makes sense, frustrating as it may-be.

Which is why I've decided to just remove the inheritance from FileInfo and bake the data right into my own class, which is fine, if it didn't still think that it was some how inheriting from a class that I'm not actually inheriting from any more. Actually I think I'm over that hurdle now. It's not really saying that I'm trying to inherit from a sealed class any more.

But seriously, I'm just spinning my wheels here, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `IObservable` is an interface.

Comment: Your class should not start with `I`, since it isn't an interface.

Comment: It looks like you're probably looking for `var files = new Subject<IFileInfo>();`

Comment: Actually I was looking for ObservableCollection. Thanks for the tip on "I". ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is right because `IObservable<T>` is an Interface not a class, so it can't be instantiated.

For more information about this interface, you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)